# Rails 4 difference between flash[:success] and :notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a bit confusion about using `flash` and `notice` in rails

What is the difference between following two piece of code

```
format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'success message' }
```

And

```
flash[:success]
```

Which one is the recommended way of doing so

Comment: its like asking why bootstrap has success and info: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts

Comment: @apneadiving My doubt is both are same but whats the difference behind it

Answer (score 3):

`flash` in it's simplest form is a Hash.  You can think of `:success` and `:notice` as such:

```
flash = { notice: 'watch out', success: 'you dodged it' }
```

You can even register your own types:

```
class ApplicationController
   add_flash_types :custom
end
```

The reason there are different types is primarily for front end formatting.  You can cycle through the flash messages and add different styles depending on the flash type.  Warning could be yellow, success is green, error is red, etc.